What does the wrench symbol mean on YouTube chat?
What does that wrench symbol mean on YouTube chat?

(screenshot from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wYyh_j0mQE)

It means the user is a moderator.
From youtube.com.

If you are moderator, you can more likely remove other people's comments, block/hide users from their channels, time users out in the live chat. And on the live chat, you see someone with a blue wrench, that classifies the user as a moderator.
Standard Moderators:
Put users in timeout in the live chat, hide users from the channel, and review potentially inappropriate messages.
Managing Moderators:
Turn live chat on or off, change participation modes, block words, and manage standard moderators such as timing them out and hiding them.

